# UITableView datasource and delegate won't connect to a custom class

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uistoryboard

I am unable to connect the datasource and delegate outlets of table view within the storyboard to my custom delegated class. I would like to delegate those table functions to another class. There is something I've fundamentally misunderstood regarding delegation, outlets and wiring things up in a storyboard.

**Background**

I have a `UIViewController` that has a view containing a `UIPickerView` and amongst other things, a `UITableView`.
I have reached the point where my `UIViewController` is too large and I would like to move the table-related functions into another class.

I have created the following class to contain those table methods such as `numberOfSectionsInTableView:`.

```
@interface ExerciseTableDelegate : NSObject <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> 

@property (strong, nonatomic) ExerciseDataController *dataController;

@end
```

I've thought to put a reference to the class above in my `UIViewController`

```
@interface ExerciseViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>
{
    UIPickerView *exercisePicker;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet ExerciseTableDelegate *tableDelegate;

@end
```

I was hoping that within the storyboard, when I drag one of the datasource or delegate outlets of my table view onto the `UITableViewController` it would give me the ability to connect to my delegated class. It didn't.

I then tried to create an object within the storyboard, giving it the class `ExerciseTableDelegate`. I could then drag the table view delegate to the object, but this isn't the same object that I setup within my `AppDelegate`.

My app delegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    ExerciseViewController *rootViewController = (ExerciseViewController *)[[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];

    ExerciseTableDelegate *tableDelegate = [[ExerciseTableDelegate alloc]init];
    ExerciseDataController *dataController = [[ExerciseDataController alloc] init];

    tableDelegate.dataController = dataController;
    rootViewController.tableDelegate = tableDelegate;

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

- Do I need to make my object a singleton and still initialise it in
  the delegate?
- Do I need to do this setup in code rather than in the
  Storyboard?
- Is creating an Object in the Storyboard the wrong idea?

I feel I am close but I think I'm doing too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want access to the instance of `ExerciseTableDelegate` that you set up in your application delegate, then you will have to connect it to your table view in code, since it won't be accessible from the storyboard - as you've found, adding a new object in the storyboard creates a new instance.

Luckily, this is pretty simple to implement. In the `viewDidLoad` method of your table view controller, add the following:

```
self.tableView.delegate = self.tableDelegate;
self.tableView.datasource = self.tableDelegate;
```

This will re-point the datasource and delegate to your separate object.

Comment: Thankyou @jrturton. That did the trick. In addition to that, I needed to do the standard thing to create an IBOutlet for the ExerciseViewControllers tableView and needed to wire that up in the storyboard.